# Required Field Validator in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, requiredfieldvalidator

I am developing a mobile application in android using eclipse and phonegap. and my question is. How will i able to create a required field validator in my registration page? or what code should i input for required field validator. Many thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your registration page is a bunch of editTexts, you can just use

```
String mString = editText.getText()
```

and then make sure that the mString has a certain length

```
mString.length()
```

or includes certain characteristics (like @ and .com for an email) For that you can just use regex (or Pattern in Android)
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

actually getText() returns an 'Editable' object, you would actually need to:

```
String mString = editText.getText().toString();
```

for that to work